# TYPO3 v12+ installation shows empty page

Tags: typo3

Am attempting to install `TYPO3 12/13`. However, the install page `/typo3/install.php` shows blank. Browser console indicates that assets links are defined but the asset files are missing for all links. A look at the assets folder `_assets` shows it's empty although asset links were generated with the page. All vendor files loaded. Page is clean with not a single character.

Also tried `typo3 setup` console command ([instructions here](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-getting-started/main/en-us/Installation/Install.html)) but it stopped working after providing database name. Database is new and have accessed it directly. Db Credentials are ok.

No errors in the database, apache logs or var log.

How would I get it to run?

Am using:

```
Composer
TYPO3 12.4 LTS (stable). Same with / 13-dev    
Windows 10
PHP 8.2.7
MySQL 8.0.33
```

Comment: Are you maybe missing some required PHP extensions? https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-getting-started/main/en-us/SystemRequirements/Index.html
You could check if all of them are loaded in phpinfo().

Comment: @Mogens I've also posted an answer here after successfully testing installation with the results from the other one. I thought it might interest you. Thank you for trying hard to help solve this problem.

Comment: Did not know about this problem with windows. A good point to throw windows in the garbage can and change to linux. ;-)

Answer (score 6):

As of TYPO3 12 the TYPO3_MODE has been removed. I had same issue, because of checking the TYPO3_MODE like this in my site_package extension.

```
defined('TYPO3_MODE') or die();
```

Search your code for:

```
TYPO3_MODE
```

and change it to:

```
TYPO3
```

Did the job for me.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Had already known about it. Don't have any of that in my files. Just confirmed. +1 coz it might just save someone a pile of time.

Answer (score 1):

This question is related to [another problem that I asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76566336/typo3-12-backend-install-page-assets-generation) a day later, supposing its answers may lead me to solve this one.

The problem is, that TYPO3 versions 12+ now have installation pages that require a JavaScript asset to load. The solution is make sure the assets are loaded. I have explained the answer in my other question. Assets not loading has to do with the PHP's `symlink` function problem not working as one would expect in Windows machines. The problem is well known, documented and many questions have been asked concerning it here in SO.

The page is empty because assets are not loading. No errors are being logged because the PHP function responsible for creating the symbolic links in the `_assets` directory to corresponding individual packages' assets is suppressed.

I have filed a bug report here; https://forge.typo3.org/issues/101181 and explained the problem and solution in depth, incase someone is interested in further details on the solution suggested, steps to reproduce the error and so on.