# TYPO3 12+ backend/install page assets generation

Tags: typo3

Been having problems loading the `typo3/install.php` page to install a fresh TYPO3 project. It doesn't display anything, not even characters. Its blank.

I also noticed that assets are computed but are not generated and remain missing when called. Would like to know where they are supposed to be generated.

I've checked the entire request process but came out empty. Does anyone know where specifically these assets are generated for the `typo3/install.php` process? Checking included the `\TYPO3\CMS\Install\Controller\InstallerController` plus the `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Page\ImportMap` and there's nothing there, only links being generated. Would very much appreciate someone pointing me in the right direction.

Am using;

```
Composer installation
Windows 10
PHP 8.2.7
MySQL 8.0.33
```

Process

```
composer create-project typo3/cms-base-distribution:^12 www
```

No problems with creating the project. It's just not installing.

Screenshot
[image]

Comment: I don't know where to search. But you could setup XDebug and analyze the install process to figure out by yourself.

Comment: @Mogens Thanks for your help again. I've done all that and still couldn't find anything, even with a step-debugger.  I've gone line by line in the classes mentioned above.

Comment: If you use PhpStorm you could break the debugger at first line in PHP scripts and then start stepping from there. Maybe you find some other classes doing what you a looking for.

Comment: Since I just had the same problem, I strongly suspect that it has to do with the [Content Security Policy (CSP)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP). Press F12 in the browser and take a closer look at the console output. Do you see any errors regarding CSP?

Comment: @quellenform No CSP errors and my browser's developer console is always up. Will edit the question to attach a screenshot of the page and console.  Also, assets come from the folder `_assets` which is empty.

Comment: @Mogens Hi Mogens, I think I may have nailed the problem. See my answer. Thanks so much for the attempt you made. Will inform of the other answer if this helps to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

After hours of debugging, the culprit seems to be in the way TYPO3 generates assets from related packages. These assets are checked and generated for every TYPO3 package during composer installation. They are calculated and recalculated every time the package autoload dump is called either by update, install or create project composer commands. This is why it was so hard to detect the problem since that would be the last place anyone would think or even suspect to check. Nevertheless is it a good and quite incredibly developed system.

The process has a [publishResources](https://github.com/TYPO3/typo3/blob/main/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Composer/PackageArtifactBuilder.php) method that creates symbolic links in the `_assets` folder where the browser fetches its assets for pages generated by TYPO3. To create the assets, the `publishResources` method employs the services of Composer's Filesystem's [relativeSymlink](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/2b18799c4451a8362c9b7e51916a45ecd83d3637/src/Composer/Util/Filesystem.php#L712) method. This is meant to create *relative* symbolic links. It uses PHP's `symlink` function for these purposes.

However, PHP's `symlink` function has been known not to work as intended in Windows OS machines. Morever, one needs administrator permissions to create such links since it uses the `mklink` program in Windows to do the work. Even with admin elevation, the creation of such links in Windows is ignored all together from the PHP function. It's like it has no effect.

Luckily, composer has a method suited just for Windows users that overcomes these issues and creates hard symbolic links in the same `Filesystem` class used to create the symlink. I've submitted a bug report here https://forge.typo3.org/issues/101181 and the means to resolve the issue which only requires the introduction of two lines and modifying of two more only. I'll leave this link here for anyone interested in more details including how to reproduce the problem.